# CSS transition on click event from another element

Tags: html, css, transition

Sorry about the title not really making sense. What I have is a "Questions or Comments" span and what I want it to do is when you click on it a form appears below (in a transition). I already tried looking at similar questions on this site but none have been able to work for what I am trying to do. Currently I have javascript giving the form the `display:block` attribute when the span is clicked. I would like to use CSS if possible. If its not possible then I will accept javasacript. Any help?
Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<span id="comment">Questions or Comments</span>
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

and the CSS:

```
#comment {
text-decoration:underline;
}

form {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display is not an animatable property. Try changing the form height or opacity. For example:

```
form {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
form.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Then just use JavaScript to toggle the class.

Answer (score -1):

The property to hide and show a div is not display, but rather

```
visibility:[hidden/show]
```

I don't believe it's possible without a javascript call - here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9xLzr6f5/) utilizing jQuery.

Comment: ryans approach works - but be aware that there may be some [browser limitations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Comment: thanks... but I am asking for a transition. If you could add that to your js fiddle that would be great

Comment: _“The property to hide and show a div is not display, but rather visibility”_ – that’s not true; _both_ can be used to “hide” an element, but with different effects on the layout.